# The optimal way to check if a query string is an int?

Tags: c#, asp.net

A question that came to one of my colleagues mind, what is the best way to check if a query string is an int. I suggested using the classic Int.Parse and try and catch, also TryParse was suggested. Actually i can't think of any other ways. Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`Int32.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) is going to be your best bet.

Answer (score 2):

TryParse is probably your best bet, since it will allow for different formats for the string, as well as tell you through a boolean value whether or not it is valid.

Answer (score 1):

I like Int32.TryParse.  You could use a regex instead I suppose, but I'm not sure there would be any point.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not too useful since you'd likely want the actual int (though it could be extended to do that).  NOTE: I wouldn't do this, but it **IS** an alternate way that he hadn't thought of.

```
bool isNumeric = true;
foreach (char c in queryString) {
    if (!char.IsDigit(c)) {
       isNumeric = false;
       break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the TryParse method.  Both are just about equal, I believe TryParse does a try{}catch{} inside of the method so I doubt there's much difference in execution.

Comment: No, TryParse definitely doesn't do a try{}catch{}. It's much faster (for invalid data) than calling Parse yourself.