# Page with id in url - should I check it is integer in Page_Load?

Tags: asp.net

If I have details page for custom film (primary keys films in database are integers), for example: http://yyy.yy/PagesDetails.aspx?filmId=5 - should I verify in Page_Load event if filmId is a number?? Because somebody can modify link, set filmId = for example 'abc' and what then?

Comment: See this post and it will answer your question [Checking Query string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/587543/the-optimal-way-to-check-if-a-query-string-is-an-int)

cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check whether it is a valid integer before using it for operation supposed for integer values.

You can write an extension method like this

```
public static bool IsNumeric(this string input)
{
  int temp;
  return int.TryParse(input, out temp);
}
```

And use it in your page load like this

```
string strFilmId=Request.QueryString["filmId"];
if(strFilmId.IsNumeric())
{
  int filmId=Convert.ToInt32(strFilmId);
  //use the integer variable now
}
else
{
  // show the message to user that the url is not valid.
}
```